# how to get type of object field which is declared as a function of String/Number/Date?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the type of an object field which has a value of String/Date/Number function. when using typeof operator it returns function. but i want to know exactly which type of function it is. is there any way to get that?

```
const obj = {
  key: String,
  key1: Number,
  key2: [String]
}

console.log(typeof obj.key) // returns function but i expect it to return string 
console.log(typeof obj.key1) // returns function but i expect it to return number
console.log(typeof obj.key2) // returns function but i expect it to return array of string
```

Comment: That's not a type declaration. That's an object containing the `String()` and `Number()` native functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the `prototype.constructor.name` property to figure out whether it's a `String` or `Number`.

```js
const obj = {
  key: String,
  key2: Number,
  key3: Date,
}

console.log('key', obj.key.prototype.constructor.name);
console.log('key2', obj.key2.prototype.constructor.name);
console.log('key3', obj.key3.prototype.constructor.name);

console.log(
  'is string?', 
  obj.key.prototype.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === 'string'
);
console.log(
  'is number?',
  obj.key2.prototype.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === 'number'
);
console.log(
  'is date?',
  obj.key3.prototype.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === 'date'
);
```

This grabs the name of the constructor function of the object, so it will work with any named function:

```js
function MyCustomType() {
  //
}
const obj = { custom: MyCustomType }

console.log(obj.custom.prototype.constructor.name);
```

**EDIT:**

```js
const obj = {
  key: String,
  key1: Number,
  key2: [String],
  key3: [],
};

function getType(arg) {
  var isArray = arg instanceof Array;
  
  if (isArray && arg.length > 0) {
    // very naive approach
    var typeofFirstItem = arg[0].prototype.constructor.name;
    
    return "Array<" + typeofFirstItem +">";
  }
  if (isArray) {
    return "Array";
  }
  return arg.prototype.constructor.name;
}

console.log(getType(obj.key))
console.log(getType(obj.key1))
console.log(getType(obj.key2))
console.log(getType(obj.key3))
```

Comment: How to get type if it is declared as [String]

Comment: @muthu what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to add conditions depending on the type. something like `if (fieldDefinition.type.prototype.constructor.name.toLowerCase() == 'string')`

Comment: @muthu so is it working? What is the `fieldDefinition.type` exactly?

Comment: @muthu so what do you exactly expect to get? Something like `Array<String>`? You won't be able to get precisely "array of strings" because the array you're using is not a typed array, and it can store an arbitrary type, i.e. `["hello world", true, 1]` is totally valid and it holds a `string`, a `boolean`, and a `number`, so `JavaScript` won't give you this exact information. Have you considered using something like `TypeScript`? It sounds like that's what you need.

Comment: Yep, I am using typescript. All i need is i want to know the type of key2 field,  is it possible to get in a same way? using prototype. `obj.key2.prototype.constructor.name.toLowerCase() === 'number'` I am expecting something similar to your solution

Comment: @muthu see my edit - there's not much you can do natively with `JavaScript` to get what you need without writing something custom like the code above. I'd suggest to create a type for your object using `interfaces`, if you're using `TypeScript` and just use that instead to type your objects.

Answer (score 0):

`String` and `Number` are keywords/ in-build functions in javascript. Since you have assigned key as String and key1 as Number, `typeof obj.key` will be same as `typeof String` and similar for key2

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to get the output as string and number instead of function?

Comment: What exactly do you want to set in the keys?

Comment: For example, if `key: "some value"` then `typeof obj.key` will be `string` and similarly if `key1: 1233` then `typeof obj.key1` will be `number`